# how can i set autocommit off programmatically in mysql with javascript/nodejs and mysql npm?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using transactions in a function using nodejs and mysql npm. currently the transactional is not working, if there is an error in insert the delete query previously gets executed and I lose the row - I assume reason is that mysql comes with autocommit already enabled. is there anyway to turn off autocommit through javascript programmatically?

```
            const mysql = require('mysql')
            const config = require('../config')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development']
            
            const dbConfig = {
                connectionLimit: 10,
                host: config.database.host,
                user: config.database.user,
                password: config.database.password,
                database: config.database.database,
            }
            
            const pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);
            
            const connection = () => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
            
                        const query = (sql, binding) => {
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                connection.query(sql, binding, (err, result) => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        reject(err);
                                    }
                                    resolve(result);
                                });
                            });
                        };
                        const release = () => {
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    reject(err);
                                }
                                resolve(connection.release());
                            });
                        };
                        resolve({ query, release });
                    });
                });
            };
            
            const query = (sql, binding) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    pool.query(sql, binding, (err, result, fields) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        resolve(result);
                    });
                });
            };
            
            module.exports = { pool, connection, query };
```

and this is my function:

```
             const connection = await db.connection();
                try {
                    await connection.query("START TRANSACTION");
                    await db.query('delete from X where id=?', [bar.id]);
                    await db.query('INSERT INTO X (...) values (...)
                    .
                    await connection.query("COMMIT");

                    } catch(e) {}
```

Comment: Did you try the manual for `mysql`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#transactions

Comment: I can manually turn it off on mysql but i am wondering if there is a way to do it through javascript so we don't have to deal with it through database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying from your pool not the connection/client where you're are starting the transaction and commiting.

Change `db.query` to `connection.query`

```
const connection = await db.connection();
    try {
        await connection.query("START TRANSACTION");
        await connection.query('delete from X where id=?', [bar.id]);
        await connection.query('INSERT INTO X (...) values (...)
        await connection.query("COMMIT");
```